# Private GitHub Packages authentication from Kubernetes deployment.yml

Tags: github, kubernetes

I'm trying to pull a docker image from a private GitHub Packages registry from within a K8s deployment.yml.
As I'm trying to avoid using personal access tokens (PAT), I'm currently trying to use something like [this script](https://gist.github.com/987Nabil/594764a7444cb5eee0636607d06f43c5) to get an app access token.
It works and I can successfully "docker login" with it, but I get a "denied" when trying to pull an image.
My Argo CD installation gives me a 401 - Unauthorized.
I double checked the permissions of the GitHub App to include packages:read and to be installed on the repo, but it just doesn't work.

Is this currently not possible or am I missing something?